# Publish from VS2022 to 2 different IIS apps renders different results

Tags: webforms, microsoft-edge, visual-studio-2022, iis-10

I have this very strange issue where a web app is switching to IE mode in Edge: I updated an existing web application. When publishing it to IIS8 (test server) the web app runs fine.
When publishing it to our production server (IIS10), Edge is switching to IE mode.

It gets even more strange: To troubleshoot, I created a new web application on IIS10. I published the same web application from VS into that newly created website. It runs fine in Edge!!

I tried several things:

- Removing the original web app on IIS10 and recreate the web app, same result. It opens Edge in IE mode.
- App pool recycle: no change
- IISReset: no change

I'm at a total loss here.

Did anyone experience this before?

Comment: Do you mean that when you create a new site in IIS10 and publish the web application to this new site, everything works fine?

Comment: That was the case.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Apparently there was a registry entry that tells what sites to render in compatibility mode. This entry is propagated throughout our company.

Comment: What is this registry entry? That may aid readers who have a similar problem in the future.

Comment: @JeremyCaney This is a company created registry key. It won't be of much help for others.